# Argument in mockImplementation() Jest

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Does anyone know the `args[3]` mean in this example?

```
createTransaction.mockImplementation((...args) => {
   const setResult = args[3]
   setResult({ ...result, approved: false })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`...args` is called [Rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters).

> while rest parameters are `Array` instances, meaning methods like `sort`, `map`, `forEach` or `pop` can be applied on it directly

Array index can be used as well.

```js
const mockImplementation = (...args) => console.log(args[3]);

mockImplementation(1,2,3,4) // 4
```

It will print the fourth element in the `args` array instance.